# Switching voltage on/off from a 9v battery using a 2n2222A transistor and an arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, switches

First of all, I'm a new hobbist trying to learn how to do these sort of things. So I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can!

I'm trying to use my Arduino, via a mechanical switch (Illustrated as button) to send a signal to the base of my transistor, in order to make my solenoid(Illustrated as a motor) respond.

I have connected the ground to the emitter, the "solenoid ground" to the collector and the positive wire of the solenoid connected directly to the battery.
The base is connected with a 1k resistor to an arduino output pin.

Seen in the sketch below.
[image]

So my problem is for some reason the transistor is only outputting 4,7 volts to my solenoid, is there something that I have misunderstood? Do I need to use another type of transistor?

I've followed this picture, to understand the difference between the pins of transistor. Mine is named: 2N2222A H331, is it the same?
[image]

I tried making a sketch more, this is my first time doing it so i hope it's not too confusing.
[image]

Comment: H331 is just a manufacturing date or batch code, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Cartoon diagrams like the one in this question are frowned upon here on Electronics.SE. Next time, click the circuit diagram button while editing your question, and add a proper schematic. Being able to read and draw proper schematics is a life skill.

Comment: @Dampmaskin Thank you very much for the information. I'll look into it. The reason I'm using this cartoonish style currently, is beacuse it's closer to my reality and what I understand and have experience with. :) I'm not that indepth yet, but soon enough!

Comment: Have you checked the battery voltage while powering the solenoid?  Is the battery voltage dropping?

Comment: You should really find a tutorial and try implementing a few existing schematics before designing your own.

Comment: @HandyHowie The voltage from the battery only drops about 1v, when pressing the button to activate the solenoid. :) The Solenoid works perfectly when tapping it on the battery itself.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've tried looking for a tutorial, that can help me do what i want to. So far been unlucky, hopeing to get some help here. :)

Comment: The transistor's emitter should be connected to Ground, and the collector connected to the solenoid.

Comment: Hi @PeterBennett I've done that, but I do still not get any voltage above 5v from the transistor. :(

Comment: Please show your circuit after you have followed my suggestions.

Comment: is your LDO backwards as well? that explains the undervoltage...

Answer (score 0):

1) Your transistor is backwards - emitter and collector reversed.
2) You need a reverse-biased diode across the motor/solenoid.

Incidentally, your 5V regulator does nothing.

Comment: Hi henros. I've tried pulling the transistor out and simply rotate it and plug it in, so far it displays a little higher voltage closer to 5 now, but not the 9v I was expecting. Sorry if I understood you wrong. :) I only have 1N4007 diodes laying around atm, can they do the job?